# Chrome crashes on screenshot using Protractor/Jasmine screenshot reporter

Tags: jasmine, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options, jasmine-reporters

I've noticed that when running my protractor E2E tests in Chrome, whenever a spec fails and my reporter tries to take a screenshot, Chrome will crash with the below error log. Tests without failures work fine.  IE and FF with failures work fine.

```
[1026/090128:ERROR:process_reader_win.cc(114)] NtOpenThread: {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights.  (0xc0000022)
[1026/090128:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 46316 not found in process
[1026/090128:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(56)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
[1026/093428:ERROR:process_reader_win.cc(114)] NtOpenThread: {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights.  (0xc0000022)
```

My thoughts are that updates have changed the access rights for automated screenshots? Or something similar.  My question would be how do I get around this and or change the privilages to allow for screenshots.

I've tried messing around with chromeOptions in my protractor config adding in things like disable-extensions and disable-web-security but no luck so far.

Tools being used:
Protractor Version: **4.0.9** 
protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter: **0.3.2**
NPM Version: **3.10.9**
Node Version: **4.4.3**
Chrome Version: **54.0.2840.71** 
ChromeDriver Version: **2.24** 
Selenium Standalone: **2.53.1**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you upgrade to the latest protractor 4.0.10 that comes with the latest webdriver-manager.

If it still fails, use a different screenshoter - here is a list of alternatives I gathered - https://github.com/azachar/protractor-screenshoter-plugin/wiki/Protractor-Screenshots-Alernatives